# how to convert from unsigned byte to an integer?

Tags: c, file, byte, ascii, extended-ascii

I am trying to read a file which includes unsigned bytes and I am trying to read them as an integer range of [0,255].

When I look at extended ascii table, when i read that "┌", it is equal to 218, but my program takes as 195 or 226 I don't know why.

This problem happens also on a lot of characters which are in extended part(more than 128).

Why can't I read as ASCII equivalent and how can I fix this?
Thanks for reply..

Here is my code,

```
int main()
{
   unsigned int temp = 0;
   int bytesread;
   int fd = open("inputs.txt", O_RDONLY);

   if(fd == -1)
   {
       printf("An error occured.. \n");
       exit(-1);
   }
   else
   {
       bytesread = read(fd, &temp, 1);
   }

   printf("%d", temp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an hexdump of the file ?

Comment: I think your file is not in ascii, you char "┌" is  store as 94e2 0a8c not da0a

Comment: @Ôrel: `0a` is the new line character, not part of the encoding of "┌".

Comment: If you are on a Unix system, type `od -xa inputs.txt` to see the actual bytes in the file in hexadecimal or `od -tuC -a inputs.txt` to see them in decimal. If the file is big, use `od -tuC -a inputs.txt | more` to control the output. You will likely see the bytes in the file are not what you think.

Comment: No reason for `unsigned int temp = 0;` and `read(fd, &temp, 1)`.  Recommend `unsigned char temp = 0;` to set that side issue away.

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing lots of 195, the input is probably in [UTF-8 character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

ASCII only goes up to 127 , there's no single standard "extended ascii".  There is [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) but that does not have `┌`.  Perhaps you refer to [CP 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) .

Your ways forward from here would fall into one of two broad approaches:

- Convert the file from UTF-8 into another encoding such as CP437, using tools for your operating system or otherwise.
- Read UTF-8 in your C program; you can either do this from scratch or use a pre-existing library.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the character is stored in the file using UTF-8 encoding.

For example, the character `┌` has a Unicode hex codepoint `250c`, and the UTF-8 byte sequence is `e2 94 8c`.  The `e2` is equal to your decimal `226` which suggests that your character may in fact be in a nearby Unicode block and UTF-8 encoded.

As has been suggested in comments, it would be very helpful if you provided a hexdump of the file, for example like this:

```sh
hexdump -C inputs.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This code

```
   bytesread = read(fd, &temp, 1);
```

reads one byte into the first byte of an `unsigned int`, which almost certainly is larger than a single byte. So where your data that you read ends up in the `int` value depends on your system.

If you're going to read a single byte, it's usually much easier to just use an `[unsigned] char` so you **always** know where it will end up. To convert an `unsigned char` into an `int`, you can just assign it:

```
int main()
{
   int fd = open("inputs.txt", O_RDONLY);

   if(fd == -1)
   {
       // perror() will tell you **WHAT** error occurred
       perror( "open()" );
       exit(-1);
   }

   // this is now an unsigned char
   unsigned char temp;

   // read() returns ssize_t, not int
   ssize_t bytesread = read( fd, &temp, sizeof( temp ) );
   if ( bytesread != sizeof( temp ) )
   {
       perror( "read()" );
       close( fd );
       exit( -1 );
   }

   close( fd );

   // there are a lot of ways to do this
   printf( "unsigned int value: %u\n", ( unsigned int ) temp );

   // this is another way - it prints the hex value
   printf( "hex value: %hhx\n", temp );

   // this prints the char value:
   printf( "char value: '%c'\n", temp;

   // this converts that unsigned char into an int:
   int intvalue = temp;

   // yes, it's that simple.
   printf( "int value: %d\n", intvalue  );

   return 0;
}
```

Note that results can be different if `sizeof( int ) == sizeof( unsigned char )`.  In that case, there can be `unsigned char` values that can not be represented as an `int` value.

Comment: This cannot explain the results observed by the OP, because `temp` is initialized to 0 and modifying an object by modifying one of its bytes is defined behavior (partially implementation-defined), so the result must be that the low addressed byte in `temp` is set to the byte read, and, regardless of the order of bytes within `temp`, this would not result in a value of 195 or 226 for an input byte of 218.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "modifying an object by modifying one of its bytes is defined behavior (partially implementation-defined)" ---> Hmmm, in unicorn land with a `unsigned` with padding (parity bits), I have doubts.  IAC, OP should be using   `unsigned char temp;`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: C 2018 6.2.5 2 says “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number,
order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.” Therefore, if I know the bytes in an object, and I modify one of them to a value I know, I can figure out the represented value using the information either explicitly specified or implementation-defined. Of course, that may be a trap value, and **using** that may result in behavior not defined by the C standard, but that is another matter.